# How to point OR redirect domain name to a specific url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I took  **domain** named(www.learneazy.com) and a **virtual private server** from godaddy

In the virtual private sever given to me , i installed Glassfish server and deployed  war file to it ,  and could able to access the Html named index.html present with context name  by typing

```
http://learneazy.com:8080/contextname/index.html
```

my question is if someone types `www.learneazy.com` how can i map it to

```
http://learneazy.com:8080/contextname/index.html
```

At present i could see the following  when someone types `learneazy.com`

**Index of /
cgi-bin/
Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at learneazy.com Port 80**

Could you please let me know how to resolve the issue ??

Comment: Does GoDaddy allow you vhost configuration? or `sudo` access?

Comment: yes i have sudo access ... could you please give me some hint on how to proceed.

Comment: `sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

Comment: should i mention this in any file ??

Comment: No, this command needs to be run from the shell. You'll have to ssh to the machine.